# array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed when using numpy and recfromcsv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looping through a bunch of files and importing their contents as numpy arrays:

```
# get the dates for our gaps
import os.path
import glob
from pathlib import Path
from numpy import recfromcsv

folder = "daily_bars_filtered/*.csv"
df_gapper_list = []
df_intraday_analysis = []
# loop through the daily gappers
for fname in glob.glob(folder)[0:2]:
    ticker = Path(fname).stem
    daily_bars_arr = recfromcsv(fname, delimiter=',')
    print(ticker)
    print(daily_bars_arr)
```

Output:

```
AACG
[(b'2021-07-15', 43796169., 2.98, 3.83, 4.75, 2.9401, 2.98,  59.39597315)
 (b'2022-01-04', 14934689., 1.25, 2.55, 2.59, 1.25  , 1.19, 117.64705882)
 (b'2022-01-05',  8067429., 1.8 , 2.3 , 2.64, 1.72  , 2.55,   3.52941176)
 (b'2022-01-07',  9718034., 1.93, 2.64, 2.94, 1.85  , 1.98,  48.48484848)]
AAL
[(b'2022-03-04', 76218689., 15.27 , 14.59, 15.4799, 14.42  , 15.71,  1.46467218)
 (b'2022-03-07', 89360330., 14.32 , 12.84, 14.62  , 12.77  , 14.59,  0.20562029)
 (b'2022-03-08', 88067102., 13.035, 13.51, 14.27  , 12.4401, 12.84, 11.13707165)
 (b'2022-03-09', 88884229., 14.44 , 14.3 , 14.75  , 14.05  , 13.51,  9.17838638)
 (b'2022-03-10', 56463182., 13.82 , 14.2 , 14.44  , 13.46  , 14.3 ,  0.97902098)
 (b'2022-03-11', 48342029., 14.4  , 14.02, 14.56  , 13.9   , 14.2 ,  2.53521127)
 (b'2022-03-14', 53284254., 14.04 , 14.25, 14.83  , 13.7   , 14.02,  5.77746077)]
```

What I then try to do is target the first column where my dates are, by doing:

```
print(daily_bars_arr[:,[0]])
```

But then I get the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a one-dimensional array with tuples in it. You want a two-dimensional array with floats in it.

Comment: @rafaelc the "rows" of the data are records, not just sequential floats. I think what is *really* wanted here is to use Pandas rather than Numpy in order to manipulate tabular data.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for your comment. I am experimenting with numpy to improve speed over my current pandas approach which is very slow

Comment: If the Pandas code is non-performant, that is almost certainly an algorithm problem. Pandas is built on top of Numpy.

Comment: What is the array `dtype`?  A structured array has fields, not columns.

Comment: Hi hpaulj it is of type <class 'numpy.recarray'>. I am trying to convert it to a 2d array

Comment: I did not ask for `type`!  Read about structured arrays here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: A structured array's fields are named, much like the columns of a dataframe..  Look at `daily_bars_arr.dtype`

Comment: (numpy.record, [('date', '<i8'), ('volume', '<f8'), ('open', '<f8'), ('close', '<f8'), ('high', '<f8'), ('low', '<f8'), ('previous_close', '<f8'), ('change', '<f8')])

Comment: `daily_bars_arr['date']` to access the first field.